# Laravel Inertia React preserve state not working

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I'm trying to reload my page but keep the filters state with [Inertia](https://inertiajs.com/).

Like this:

```
const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useState([]);
    
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);

const fetchProducts = (page) => {
    Inertia.get(
      `/products?page=${page}`,
      { filters },
      {
        preserveState: true,
        preserveScroll: true,
        only: ['products'],
        onSuccess: (response) => {
          setAllProducts(allProducts.concat(response.props.products.data));
          page += 1;
        }
      }
    )
});
```

The problem is that `filters` and `allProducts` are reset even though `preserveState = true`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "reload my page"? State in React is not preserved on "real" page refresh.

Maybe you can save data in local storage, then load it by useEffect. Another solution is to store data you want to keep between pages in [Laravel session storage](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#storing-data).

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller try to use `withQueryString()` method.
as a Example:

```
$allUsers = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())
            ->when($request->input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
                $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                });
            })
            ->paginate(10)
            ->withQueryString()
            ->onEachSide(2);
```